# FreeSWITCH: Error when loading config with Lua insted of CURL

Tags: curl, lua, freeswitch

I have working setup of freeswitch with xml_curl module option

```
<param name="gateway-url" 
       value="http://localhost:444/index.php" 
       bindings="directory|dialplan|configuration"/>
```

And I want to change xml_curl module on lua module, so I turned off xml_curl module and set next options to lua module

```
<param name="xml-handler-script"
       value="/var/www/callcenter/current/freeswitch/index.lua"/>
<param name="xml-handler-bindings"
       value="dialplan|directory|configuration"/>
```

but with it module sofia throws error `Error Creating SIP UA for profile`. Is there any issues with module lua? Maybe I should set some other options for lua module?

I have FreeSWITCH 1.6

Comment: First use `,` instead of `|`. Next check what your Lua code returns to FS. It shuld return *full* XML structure for configuration starting with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><document type="freeswitch/xml"><section name="configuration">`

Comment: Lua reading same files as CURL so there should be no difference. Changing `|` to `,` doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

`mod_lua` is loaded during initial startup, then modules loaded after initial startup may have their configuration served by the bound script whenever they request configuration, which for many modules is on loading.

```
<configuration name="lua.conf" description="LUA Configuration">
   <settings>
      <param name="xml-handler-script" value="configuration.lua"/>
      <param name="xml-handler-bindings" value="configuration"/>
   </settings>
</configuration>
```

Then when the module is started, XML_REQUEST will have:

```
key_value = 'iax.conf'|'event_socket.conf'|sofia.conf'|...
key_name = 'name'
section = 'configuration'
tag_name = 'configuration'
```

Answer (score 0):

Half a decade later in case someone else hit this:

The problem is that the `${foo}` variables are not expanded by default. This code will enable it:

```lua
local rpc = require("rpc")    
    
freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE", table.concat({    
    "Loading configuration " ..    
    tostring(XML_REQUEST["section"]) ..     
    " -> "..    
    tostring(XML_REQUEST["key_value"]) ..    
    " using lua\n"    
}, " "))    
    
local ret    
    
rpc.context(function(rpc_api)    
    local conf = rpc_api.get_configuration {    
        section   = XML_REQUEST.section,      
        tag_name  = XML_REQUEST.tag_name,     
        key_name  = XML_REQUEST.key_name,                                                                
        key_value = XML_REQUEST.key_value,                                                               
        params    = params and params:serialize("json") or false,                                        
    }    
        
    ret = type(conf.result) == "string" and conf.result or conf.result[1]    
end)    
    
assert(ret, tostring(XML_REQUEST["section"]) .. " "..  tostring(XML_REQUEST["key_value"]) .. " lacks a config generator")                              
                                     
-- Apply the global variables        
local function apply_globals(txt)    
    return txt:gsub('([$]+%b{})', function(w)    
        local var = w:match("[{]([^}]+)[}]")    
        freeswitch.consoleLog("WARNING", "Apply global: "..var .. " = ".. tostring(freeswitch.getGlobalVariable(var)).."\n")    
        return freeswitch.getGlobalVariable(var)                                                         
    end)                                                                                                 
end                                                                                                      
                                                                                                         
XML_STRING = apply_globals(ret)    
    
if XML_REQUEST.key_value == "sofia.conf" then    
    freeswitch.consoleLog("WARNING", "CONF   " .. XML_STRING.. "\n")    
end
```

Also make sure your document has the extra headers which wont be found in the normal files:

```lua
local CONF_HEADER = [[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <document type="freeswitch/xml">                                                                                                            
        <section name="configuration">
]]

local CONF_FOOTER = [[
    </section>
</document>
]]

return CONF_HEADER..read_xml_from_disk()..CONF_FOOTER
```